# Appending background image to jumbotron class from Google API

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying to append an background image to my jumbotron after a user submits their location in the form. The URL works fine, but the appended image never ends up in the jumbotron as background. I will be grateful for any help.

My HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <h3 class="greeting">Where would you like to move?</h1>
    <form id="form-container" class="form-container">
        <label for="street">Street: </label><input type="text" id="street" value="">
        <label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" value="">
        <p><button class ="btn btn-success btn-md "id="submit-btn">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    height: 400px;
}
.bgimg {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var street = $("#street").val();

var city = $("#city").val();

var fullLocation = street +", " + city;

var googleUrl = '"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=1000x400&location=' + fullLocation + '"';

$(".jumbotron").append("<img class='bgimg' src=" +googleUrl+ ">");
```

Comment: The HTML is not well-formed: 2 starting div's, but only one ending (and what [user Ionut mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403393/appending-background-image-to-jumbotron-class-from-google-api/41403551#41403551)). Use of an HTML validator, e.g. [https://validator.w3.org/nu/](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

1. You close the `<h3>` with `</h1>` which is not good:

Modified this:

```
<h3 class="greeting">Where would you like to move?</h1>
```

to:

```
<h3 class="greeting">Where would you like to move?</h3>
```

2. Verify if you added the `jQuery` library.
3. You are not appending a background image, you are actually appending an `<img ...`. Add the `on` click event handler with the `preventDefault()` and it should work.

If you would want to append a background image your code should look something like this:

```
$(".jumbotron").css('background-image', 'url(' + googleUrl+ ')');
```

See the working snippet:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var street = $("#street").val();

  var city = $("#city").val();

  var fullLocation = street +", " + city;

  var googleUrl = '"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=1000x400&location=' + fullLocation + '"';

  $(".jumbotron").append("<img class='bgimg' src=" + googleUrl + ">");
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 400px;
}
.bgimg {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <h3 class="greeting">Where would you like to move?</h3>
    <form id="form-container" class="form-container">
      <label for="street">Street:</label>
      <input type="text" id="street" value="Wall Street">
      <label for="city">City:</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" value="New York, NY, United States">
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-md " id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the issue